# How to convert Word DOCX to HTML using java

Tags: java, html, apache-poi, converters, docx

I am using the following code:
My code is converting **Doc** document to **HTML** only. I need to convert **Docx** document to **HTML**.

```
try
{
    HWPFDocumentCore wordDocument = WordToHtmlUtils.loadDoc(new FileInputStream("C:\\DOC.doc"));

    WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(
            DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument());
    wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(wordDocument);

    org.w3c.dom.Document htmlDocument = wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(htmlDocument);
    StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
    serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
    out.close();

    String result = new String(out.toByteArray());
    System.out.println(result);

    ConvertDocxBigToXHTML html = new ConvertDocxBigToXHTML();
    html.creatHTML(result);
}

catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can someone help me to what changes i have to do above this code

Comment: What is the Problem with your code?

Comment: when i upload docx file my code is not working

Comment: Do you get an Exception? If yes, what is that?

Comment: What means `not working`?

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\test232.docx (The system cannot find the file specified)` but the **c drive** have test232.docx  document

Comment: I don't know Apache Poi, but, according to this link, for converting docx you sholud use XWPF instead of HWPF:
https://poi.apache.org/document/
Have you tried that? It says: "The partner to HWPF for the new Word 2007 .docx format is XWPF."

Comment: yes i tried XWPF this is my code ``File file = new File("C:\\test.html");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\testhtml.html");

            XHTMLConverter.getInstance().convert(document , fos , null);``

Comment: Did you get an Exception for that, too?

Comment: no. for this code i didn't  get any Exception but its not converting properly

Comment: XWPF is definitely for .docx format, so the first step would be to change it

Comment: ya how can i modify the first steps ???